# Binding to a treeview programatically not working in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, treeview

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view#tree-view-using-data-binding) article to try and programmatically bind data to a treeview (I'm on 1903).

In a brand new UWP app, I have the following code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var items = new List<Item>();
    var rootItem = new Item();
    rootItem.Name = "Root Item";
    rootItem.Children.Add(new Item() { Name = "test child 1" });
    items.Add(rootItem);

    var treeView = new TreeView();
    treeView.ItemsSource = items;
    stackPanel.Children.Add(treeView);
}
```

`Item` looks like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Children { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

This appears to be the exact structure outlined in the above article.  However, when I run the application, I get this:

[image: UWP App TreeView]

My guess is that I need to do, or set something that tells this treeview, or the collection that it has children - but I can't see what that might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an `ItemTemplate` as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view#tree-view-using-data-binding).

You could use the [XamlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader) class to do this programmatically. Something like this:

```
const string Xaml = "<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><TreeViewItem ItemsSource=\"{Binding Children}\" Content=\"{Binding Name}\"/></DataTemplate>";
treeView.ItemTemplate = XamlReader.Load(Xaml) as DataTemplate;
```

Comment: I had tried this sort of thing, and couldn't get it to work.  I've tried your code, and three of four variations, but none of them seem to be a valid template.

Comment: Sorry - my bad - it works fine.  There's a type in your answer, the root note has a /> at the start, but SO won't let me edit it

Comment: @CuriousDev: Edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you use C# to build a TreeView, I recommend adding a TreeViewNode using traversal.

Due to the lack of instructions, TreeView does not automatically handle the Children of the Item. In the documentation you provide, the TreeView has a `DataTemplate` directive, so the children can render.

You can change code like this:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var items = new List<Item>();
    var rootItem = new Item();
    rootItem.Name = "Root Item";
    rootItem.Children.Add(new Item() { Name = "test child 1" });
    items.Add(rootItem);
    var treeView = new TreeView();

    foreach (var root in items)
    {
        var rootNode = new TreeViewNode() { Content = root.Name };
        if (root.Children.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var child in root.Children)
            {
                rootNode.Children.Add(new TreeViewNode() { Content = child.Name });
            }
        }
        treeView.RootNodes.Add(rootNode);
    }
    stackPanel.Children.Add(treeView);
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: I had actually just changed it from this approach.  The main reason being that I needed to store more information against the node than a single string.

Comment: Hi, If you choose to create a TreeView this way, subsequent modifications to the node need to be done by looking up the node. If you want to render a TreeView using a dataset, it's best to use a `DataTemplate` to bind the data.

Comment: That was the advice of @mm8, but I can't seem to feed the template in programatically.